# How to type dynamically created class methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

I have a class which is used to send requests to server.

There's a `ROUTES` dictionary which is a map of class method names to the server endpoint used in `request` function.

These methods are added to class in `__init__` with `setattr`. I could've just added these methods to the class, but there are a lot of them and I hate code duplication.

Class looks like this:

```py
ROUTES = {
    "send_test": ["GET", "/test/"],
    "send_start": ["GET", "/start/"]
}

class Response(TypedDict):
    ...

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        for mname, endpoint in ROUTES.items():
            setattr(self, mname, self.make_request_func(endpoint[0], endpoint[1]))

    def make_request_func(self, method, path): 
        def _func(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.request(method, path, *args, **kwargs)
        return _func

    def request(self, method, path, data: dict = {}, files: Optional[dict] = None) -> Response:
        ...
```

I basically need these `send_test` and `send_start` methods to just point to an alias of `request` function, but without `method` and `path` arguments, only `data` and `files`.

I have a very basic knowledge of python's typing, I will appreciate any additional explanation of typing this!

Comment: Why make these instance attributes instead of instance methods?

Comment: @chepner They are methods, just the the function is made dynamically

Comment: They're not methods, because you're attaching the functions to an *instance* of `Client`, not `Client` itself.

Comment: How big is `ROUTES`? The indirection of iterating over its contents makes this just dynamic enough that type hints won't be of any use. I would consider just writing `send_test = makerequest("GET", "/test")`, etc, at the class level, with `makerequest` returning a suitable function that calls `request`. `makerequest` itself can be typed so that `send_test` et al. are appropriately typed.

Comment: @chepner you're right, they are not.
oh, this approach is actually great. do I need to extract `makerequest` and `request` outside of class to do this? class has some attributes for requests to work, like `base_url`, etc.

Comment: `request` stays a method. `makerequest` can be moved outside the class, though it doesn't strictly need to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to be a little less DRY and define instance methods explicitly, the following should work. (Let's face it, the repeated calls to `makerequest` aren't really any more repetitive than the original definition of `ROUTES`.)

```
from typing import Optional, Callable

def makerequest(method: str, path: str) -> Callable[[Client, Optional[dict], Optional[dict]], Response]:
    def wrapper(self: Client, data: Optional[dict] = None, files: Optional[dict] = None) -> Response:
        return self.request(method, path, data, files)
    return wrapper

class Client(object):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        ...

    send_test = makerequest("GET", "/test/")
    send_start = makerequest("GET", "/start/")

    def request(self, method, path, data: Optional[dict] = None, files: Optional[dict] = None) -> Response:
        ...
```

(I took the liberty of replacing your default `dict` value with `None`, to avoid problems with mutable default values.)

With this, `mypy` reports the revealed type of `Client.send_test` as

```
tmp.py:32: note: Revealed type is "def (tmp.Client, Union[builtins.dict[Any, Any], None], Union[builtins.dict[Any, Any], None]) -> TypedDict('tmp.Response', {})"
```

Adapting this to allow defining the aliases by iterating over `ROUTES` will be at best, I think, a mess, and at worst not possible, due to the class attributes `send_test` etc not being statically defined.

---

If typing weren't an issue, I would recommend a class decorator to define the methods.

```
ROUTES = {...}

def add_aliases(d: dict):
    def _(cls):
        for name, args in d.items():
            setattr(cls, name, makereqeust(*args))
        return cls
    return _


def makerequest(method, path):
    ...


@add_aliases(ROUTES)
class Client:
    def request(self, ...):
        ...
```

The problem is annotating `add_aliases` and `_` in a way that captures the idea of the class that `_` returns having methods of the desired type, since nothing can be inferred from the body of `add_aliases` alone.

Comment: Wow! That's just brilliant. Thank a lot!!